# "git merge"- already up to date

Tags: git

I'm facing a problem when I checkout a new branch named "Christmas" from branch "develop" and make some changes to it.

1. Now I want to merge "develop" into "Christmas", then solve the conflicts.
2. After that merge "Christmas" into "develop" and push it to update the remote "develop".

But it got some problems. In step1 it shows Already up to date, and in step2 there are still many conflicts. What should I do? please help me !

Comment: Have you committed anything on Step1 to the branch Christmas?

Comment: yes, I committed

Comment: Can you show the `git reflog` to see what you actually did?

Answer (score 1):

if you checkout to `Christmas` from `develop`, The commits you made in `develop` are in `Christmas`. you can even delete the `develop` from local and recreate the `develop` from `Christmas` with the following command.

it would be better if you paste the log with `git reflog` command to see what you actually did.

To delete the old develop

```
git branch -d develop
```

Recreate the `develop` the from `Christmas`

```
git checkout -b develop
```

After that, Push the develop to remote

```
git push origin develop
```

Make sure you have committed the `Christmas`

Answer (score 0):

`Christmas` branch is based on develop, therefore when you do: `git merge develop` you are already up to date. There are no new changes in the develop branch that need to be added to your branch.

You should do instead:

```
git fetch
git merge origin/develop
```

To update your feature branch with the latest changes - this will show you the conflicts that you need to solve.

Personally I prefer to use `get rebase origin/develop` but it is just the way I like to order the commits.

Comment: yes  it should show because you have created the `Christmas` from develop

Answer (score 0):

1. Now I want to merge "develop" into "Christmas", then solve the conflicts.

   > You have created `Christmas` branch from `develop`. Hence, you should merge `Christmas` into `develop` branch because commits of develop will be already present and up to date.

```
git checkout Christmas
git merge develop
```

Once you run merge then you will be able to see the conflicts, if any.

2. After that merge "Christmas" into "develop" and push it to update the remote "develop".

   > This merge won't be required, if you have merged in previous step. You can simply push the changes to remoted using `git push develop`

Answer (score 0):

your steps does not look right.  Normally, a short-lived feature branch should works like this:

1. You have a base branch you want to change (in your case, `develop`)
2. You create a new feature branch (in your case, `Christmas`) base on your base branch
3. Checkout the feature branch, do your work and commit
4. After you are satisfied with whatever you have in your feature branch, merge your feature branch into the base branch (you are doing the opposite)
5. Push the new base branch to remote.

The related commands are something like this:

```
1. Assume you have "develop" branch, and you have checked that out
> git checkout develop

2. Create new feature branch "Christmas"
> git checkout -b Christmas
  # or  git branch Christmas ; git checkout Christmas

3. Do your work and commit
> git commit -m "your message"

4. Merge feature branch back to base branch
> git checkout develop    # go back to your base branch first, and make sure it is 
                          # up-to-date
> git merge Christmas     # merge change in your feature branch into your base branch

  An alternative of merge is to rebase your feature branch onto the base branch:

> git checkout Christmas  # rebase works in opposite: you should be in your 
                          # branch, and rebase onto the base
> git rebase develop

  The above two commands can be combined as
> git rebase develop Christmas

5. Push your local "develop" branch to remote
(develop)> git push origin develop
```

Although your questions is not applicable to proper usage of Git, I will still try to answer:

You create `Christmas` from `develop`.  Without any change in `develop`, it means your `Christmas` has already contains all changes you found in `develop`.  Therefore when you merge `develop` into `Christmas` (for which is a wrong usage), nothing will happen as there is nothing in `develop` you need to merge into `Christmas`, hence the "Already up to date" message